# Standards for better <iframe> accessibility in JAWS?

Tags: iframe, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

Is there any standard practice to be followed for better accessibility in case of `iframe`?

What all the things we need to take care for `iframe` accessibility?

What all the points should consider for `iframe` from narrator perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short list:

- Your `iframe` must have a title
- The inner document must be accessible
- Do not disable scrolling in the iframe
- Check that using your browser zoom will correctly resize the iframe so that it's still readable

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your response. I am clear with 3 points out of 4 however bit confuse about second point "Inner document must be accessible" how to achieve it? Could you please provide me sample on the same?

Comment: @user3249448 This just means that the document inside the iframe must respect WCAG as if it was a standalone URL (you can open it in your browser, or use any accessibility assessment tool to check for its validity).

Comment: Okay one more question. Is it expected that once iframe receives an focus it should navigate through using TAB keys inside iframe? coz iframe may contains links and buttons.

Comment: @user3249448 yes. it's the default behavior.